# "Breakpoint will not be hit. No symbols have have been loaded" only in JavaScript files. VS 2019

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-debugging

I am unable to debug any javascript in my MVC app. I always get this error. Currently I have a separate js file. But I have also tested with js in script tags. I am able to set breakpoints everywhere else in my application including cs and cshtml files. I have had this problem ever since I started this project.

I know this may seem like a repeat question. But I have tried a lot of things. I have enabled javascript debugging, running in debug mode, debugging info is "full".

The project dll says "Native debugger skipped loading symbols for managed module" in the modules. When I try to manually load symbols, it shows there is a project pdb file. But when I choose it, it says "A matching symbol file was not found".

I don't understand these dlls and symbols very well. Is there something going on here?

Any help would be great, as I have wasted a lot of time on this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug JavaScript in Visual Studio (VS2017 and up), you have to use Chrome or Edge. I was using Firefox (stupid me) and, of course, it didn't work. Just thought it was good to know.
Check out [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/debug-nodejs?view=vs-2019) for more details.

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could [accept it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.